# Return any rows where id in one table does not match 1 of 4 other tables

Tags: sql

I am trying to find all rows from one table that did not get copied into at least 1 of 4 other tables.

The Title table has a column named titleid.  I want to be sure that all rows in the Title table are copied into a view.  We have 4 possible views.  It could be in TitleView, TitleView2, TitleView3 or TitleView4.

I have tried not in, joins unions and exists without luck.  Here is the latest attempt.  This returns a titleid  that is not in each View instead of considering all 4 as one giant table.

```
select ct.titleid
from Title ct
where titleid not in (select distinct titleid from TitleView])
   or titleid not in (select distinct titleid from TitleView2])
   or titleid not in (select distinct titleid from TitleView3)
   or titleid not in (select distinct titleid from TitleView4)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want `and`:

```
select ct.titleid
from Title ct
where titleid not in (select titleid from TitleView]) and
      titleid not in (select titleid from TitleView2) and
      titleid not in (select titleid from TitleView3) and
      titleid not in (select titleid from TitleView4);
```

Note that `select distinct` is not needed in the subquery.

Also, I don't recommend `not in` with subqueries.  It does not do what you want if *any* value from the subqueries are `NULL`.  Also, you should qualify all column references.  If one of the subqueries has a different name for `titleid`, this does not do what you intend.

I recommend instead:

```
select ct.titleid
from Title ct
where not exists (select 1 from TitleView v where v.titleid = ct.titleid) and
      not exists (select 1 from TitleView2 v where v.titleid = ct.titleid) and
      not exists (select 1 from TitleView3 v where v.titleid = ct.titleid) and
      not exists (select 1 from TitleView4 v where v.titleid = ct.titleid);
```